# SQL help Building Cases based on dates of service every 30day gap

Tags: sql

I was wondering if someone could help me out with the following logic.  I'm trying to create a new case number every 30 days a unique patient has a gap in services.  Currently the case numbers aren't going past 2.

```
select t1.*,
dense_rank() over(
partition by t1.D_UNIQUEPATIENTID
order by t1.d_ServiceStartDate) episode_rank
into #temp2
from #temp1 t1

-- select * from #temp2
```

--This is every episode and the days between episodes.

```
select *,
isnull(abs(datediff(day,t1.d_ServiceStartDate, (select top 1 t2.[d_ServiceEndDate] from #temp2 as t2 where t2.D_UNIQUEPATIENTID =t1.D_UNIQUEPATIENTID
and t2.episode_rank < t1.episode_rank order by t2.episode_rank desc))),0) as day_count, 1 AS e2
into #temp3
from #temp2 as t1

SELECT *
,(CASE WHEN t.day_count > 30 THEN t.e2 + 1 ELSE t.e2 end)AS Case_Num
into #temp4
FROM #temp3 AS t

-- select * from #temp4
```

-- This should return the $amt per case, per member

```
select D_UNIQUEPATIENTID, Case_Num,min(d_ServiceStartDate) as 'Start_Date',
max(d_ServiceEndDate) as End_Date,Sum(Visits)as Visits,sum(allowed) as 'Allowed Total'
from #temp4
where [d_IncurredPD] between '201801' and'201906'
group by D_UNIQUEPATIENTID, Case_Num
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images). Take a look at [mcve] before you start!

Comment: And add a tag for the dbms you're using. (Perhaps <sql-server>?)

Comment: What dbms is this???  SQL is just a language used by multiple dbms vendors.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to create a new case number every 30 days a unique patient has a gap in services.

It is unclear whether you want this *per patient* or *overall*.  I assume per patient, although the solution can be adapted.

I have no idea what how the code sample relates to this question.  So, I'll write this generically:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_servicedate >= servicedate - interval '30 day'
                then 0 else 1
           end) over (partition by patientid order by servicedate) as patient_case
from (select t.*,
             lag(servicedate) over (partition by patientid order by servicedate) as prev_servicedate
      from t
     ) t;
```

Note that this uses standard date functions; these usually vary by database but you haven't specified the database (as I write this).